# Prove that $\{n^nz^n\}$ converges if and only if $z=0$, where $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Prove that $\{n^nz^n\}$ converges if and only if $z=0$, where $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

My Try:

If $z=0$ then the limit is $0$. But I am stuck in proving that if $\{n^nz^n\}$ converges, then $z=0$. Tried to show that the sequence is unbounded when $z\neq 0$. I could show it for the case where $|z|\geq 1$. But how do I show it for the case where $|z|< 1$. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: If $z\ne0$,, then, for every $n>2/|z|$, $|n^nz^n|>2^n$, hence $n^nz^n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Apply the Archimedean property to $|z|$ and $1$.